# How I can get to work on template string in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I try to use the template string, in ASP.NET MVC.

something with the function below, but I can get the vb. can not recognize that template string. someone knows, if I need to do something to configuration on VB.NET / ASP.NET MVC, thank you

```
var fila;

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    fila = data[i];
    contenido += "<tr>";
    contenido += "<td>" + fila.IIDTIPOUSUARIO + "</td >";
    contenido += "<td>" + fila.NOMBRE + "</td>";
    contenido += "<td>" + fila.DESCRIPCION + "</td>";
    contenido += `
                <td>
                    <button class ='btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></button>
                    <button class ='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></button>
                     </td
               `;

    contenido += "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: That's not VB...it's C#

Comment: If you meant C#, in order to use "template strings" like JS they're done with string interpolation and begin with a $ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: yes, it's JS. Thank you